Is there a radar that works above and below water?
Let's think about a large vertical wall, say 200x40 meters for one half immersed in water (20 m above and 20 m below).
A small robot can move on the surface of this wall. It's not important for the question how the vehicle works. The only limitation is I cannot use any magnetic sensor since the wall has a lot of metallic stuff inside.
I would like to find out its position (x, y) on the wall. I cannot use GPS since it goes underwater and the precision would be too low even when above the water level. I need at least 0.5 meters. For the same reasons I cannot use any optical devices (i.e. laser beams).
I was thinking about placing two "radars" at the two top corners of the wall. If they can detect the distance and the azimuth of the target (my robot) I can estimate its position.
But they should be able to detect the target even when it's underwater (hence I cannot use the ultra-sonic sensors).
Is there such a radar? Which (available) technology could do this?
The question is similar to this, but it's not a dupe since my constraints are quite different.

probably not outside of military applications

the electromagnetic waves used by radar will not readily pass through water. Ultrasonic might work, but you indicated they cannot be used.
one technique that might work is to attach two cords each spooling from one corner of the wall. With encoders on the spools you can measure how far the cord has extended from the spool. This will let you use triangulation to detect where the object if on the wall.

Much lower tech than radar: Put location marks on the wall and "look" at them with a waterproof camera.
